# Consultas XQuery

Tags: xml, sql, xquery

Estoy realizando una tarea en Basex y en la que debo realizar una serie de consultas XQuery, para ello tengo un archivo XML:

```
<clase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Tarea_6.xsd">
  <alumnos>
    <alumno cod="n12344345">
      <apenom>Alcalde García, Luis</apenom>
      <direc>Las Manos, 24</direc>
      <pobla>Lamadrid</pobla>
      <telef>942756645</telef>
    </alumno>
    <alumno cod="n43483437">
      <apenom>González Pérez, Olga</apenom>
      <direc>Miraflor 28 - 3A</direc>
      <pobla>Torres</pobla>
      <telef>942564355</telef>
    </alumno>
    <alumno cod="n88234942">
      <apenom>Fernández Díaz, María</apenom>
      <direc>Luisa Fernanda 53</direc>
      <pobla>Miera</pobla>
      <telef>942346945</telef>
    </alumno>
  </alumnos>
  <asignaturas>
    <asignatura cod="a1" nombre="FH"/>
    <asignatura cod="a2" nombre="FOL"/>
    <asignatura cod="a3" nombre="ISO"/>
    <asignatura cod="a4" nombre="LMSGI"/>
    <asignatura cod="a5" nombre="PAR"/>
    <asignatura cod="a6" nombre="GBD"/>
  </asignaturas>
  <notas>
    <nota alum="n12344345" asig="a1" calificacion="4"/>
    <nota alum="n43483437" asig="a1" calificacion="5"/>
    <nota alum="n88234942" asig="a1" calificacion="8"/>
    <nota alum="n12344345" asig="a2" calificacion="10"/>
    <nota alum="n43483437" asig="a2" calificacion="7"/>
    <nota alum="n88234942" asig="a2" calificacion="6"/>
    <nota alum="n12344345" asig="a3" calificacion="3"/>
    <nota alum="n88234942" asig="a3" calificacion="6"/>
    <nota alum="n12344345" asig="a4" calificacion="8"/>
    <nota alum="n43483437" asig="a4" calificacion="4"/>
    <nota alum="n12344345" asig="a5" calificacion="6"/>
    <nota alum="n12344345" asig="a6" calificacion="9"/>
  </notas>
</clase>
```

Las dudas las tengo en las siguientes consultas:

1. "¿Cuántos módulos hay?"

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    for $x in doc("Tarea_6.xml")//asignatura
count $x
return 
<asignatura>{$x}</asignatura>
```

y el resultado es este:

```
<asignatura>1</asignatura>
<asignatura>2</asignatura>
<asignatura>3</asignatura>
<asignatura>4</asignatura>
<asignatura>5</asignatura>
<asignatura>6</asignatura>
```

Pero entiendo que debería ser únicamente

```
<asignatura>6</asignatura>
```

La otra consulta con dudas es la siguiente:

2.- Obtener los nombres de los alumnos matriculados en LMSGI y sus notas ordenado por notas.
Y para la cual, he redactado el siguiente código:

```
for $x in doc("Tarea_6.xml")//apenom, $i in doc("Tarea_6.xml")//nota
where $i/nota[@asig='a4']
order by  $i/nota
return 
<apenom>{$x}</apenom> and
<nota>{$i}</nota>
```

En este caso no me da resultados, obciamente debo tener cosas mal en el código, os agradecería por ello que me podáis ayudar en arreglarlo.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el primer ejercicio tienes varios errores:

```
for $x in doc("Tarea_6.xml")//asignatura
count $x
return 
<asignatura>{$x}</asignatura>
```

Estás guardando en `$x` todos los registros de asignatura, pero `count $x` lo estás ejecutando mal, debería ser `count($x)`, pero es que dicho resultado no lo estás guardando en variable alguna, por lo que no lo puedes mostrarlo, para ello tienes que usar `let`.

Este es el código corregido:

```
for $x in /clase/asignaturas
let $asignaturas := count($x/asignatura)
return 
<asignatura>{$asignaturas}</asignatura>
```

Esto devolverá:

```
6
```

En el otro ejercicio tienes los siguientes errores (este es tu código):

```
for $x in doc("Tarea_6.xml")//apenom, $i in doc("Tarea_6.xml")//nota
where $i/nota[@asig='a4']
order by  $i/nota
return 
<apenom>{$x}</apenom> and
<nota>{$i}</nota>
```

En `$x` estás guardando directamente los nombres, pero resulta que tienes que mostrar los que estén matriculados en `LM`. Tu problema es que el nombre no genera ninguna relación con la matrícula, ni con las notas. Así que tu primer problema es que no estabas guardando los nodos correctos.

Para corregirlo tendrás que guardar los alumnos en `$x`, o más bien todo el alumnado, en `$i` estás haciendo algo parecido, tienes que guardar la nota, que es la que tiene el atributo del `código` del alumno.

Así pues, para resumir, tienes que generar una relación entre el `dni` del alumno y la nota, como la nota ya tiene un atributo del código de la asignatura, no te haría falta otro vector.

Te dejo el código corregido.

```
for $x in /clase/alumnos/alumno,
$i in clase/notas/nota
where ($x/@cod = $i/@alum) and $i/@asig = "a4"
order by $i/@calificacion
return 
<apenom>{$x/apenom}</apenom>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias David! Perfecta aclaración